# Why i do not get JSON use Decodable?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decodable

I try get json but it doesn't work for me. What i'm doing wrong? [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTzGf.png)
[My struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNK1c.png)

```
struct Stock: Decodable {
  let category_name: String?
  let privileges: [StockInfo]?
}

struct StockInfo: Decodable {
  let id: String?
  let active_to: String?
  let title: String?
  let title_size: String?
  let preview_picture_path: String?
  let preview_picture_text: String?
  let picture_text_size: String?
  let marked: String?
  let preview_text: String?
  let code_block: [CodeBlockInfo]?    
}

struct CodeBlockInfo: Decodable {
  let button_title: String?
  let button_font_color: String?
  let button_back_color: String?
  let type: String?
  let code_text: String?
  let code_pict: String?
  let description: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- CodeBlock is a dictionary not an array

```
let code_block:CodeBlockInfo
```

2- Decode like this

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Stock].self,from:jsonData)
```

3- If you're sure that a key will always return remove the trailing `?`

Comment: Thx sir. Problems was in code_block... I thinked this is array. Now all work.